# Importing Text Files with Implied Decimals as Currency in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2013

I have a fixed-width text file with implied decimals which I need to import into an Access 2013 table with columns of Currency datatype.

E.g., the text file contains the following data:

```
654321
987654
321098
```

The Import Specification is as follows:

```
File Format = "Fixed Width"
Decimal Symbol = "."

Field Name = "PaidAmount"
Data Type = "Currency"
Start = 1
Width = 6
```

The resulting table in Access is:

```
PaidAmount
$654,321.00
$987,654.00
$321,098.00
```

My desired result in Access is:

```
PaidAmount
$6,543.21
$9,876.54
$3,210.98
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the *initial Import*?

(Although I realize that it is possible, I am not interested in solutions involving dividing the PaidAmount column by 100 or modifying the text file prior to import.  I want to know if there is a way to get Access to import the data in my desired format without pre- or post-processing.)

Comment: I wonder how should a machine understand your needs to format/convert a 6 digit number into ####.## unless you tell it and how to?? i'm affright, you cannot edit the values while importing so you are left with those 2 options you don't want to do (pre or post processing). Any reason you don't want to do pre/post processing?

Comment: I was hoping that there might be some undocumented option in the Text Import Wizard which would enable me to accomplish this without post-processing.  The file I am importing is very large and I was hoping to complete data conversion in a single pass.